# List using Nodes

Tags: java, list, nodes

we are learning about linked list using nodes and I'm not sure if i'm doing this right. We are suppose to just make a simple list but when I go to run the program, I'm getting nullpointerException pointing to showList() method but when I try to not use that method, then nothing prints out at all. Please any help is greatly appreciated.

```
 public class node {
      public int dataitems; 
      public node next; 
      node front;

public void initList(){
    front = null;
}

public node makeNode(int number){
    node newNode;
    newNode = new node();
    newNode.dataitems = number;
    newNode.next = null;
    return newNode;
}

public boolean isListEmpty(node front){
    boolean balance;
    if (front == null){
        balance = true;
    }
    else {
        balance = false;
    }
    return balance;

}

public node findTail(node front) {
    node current;
    current = front;
    while(current.next != null){
        //System.out.print(current.dataitems);
        current = current.next;

    } //System.out.println(current.dataitems);
    return current;
}

public void addNode(node front ,int number){
    node tail;
    if(isListEmpty(front)){
        front = makeNode(number);
    } 
    else {
        tail = findTail(front);
        tail.next = makeNode(number);
    }
}

public void printNodes(int len){

    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < len; j++){
        addNode(front, j);
    }  showList(front);
}

public void showList(node front){
    node current;
    current = front;
    while ( current.next != null){
        System.out.print(current.dataitems);
        current = current.next;
    }
    System.out.println(current.dataitems);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
     node x = new node();

     x.printNodes(50);
    } 

       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has to do with the variable scoping of your addNode method.

```
public void addNode(node front ,int number){
    node tail;
    if(isListEmpty(front)){
        front = makeNode(number); //reassigns the node front parameter
    } 
    else {
        tail = findTail(front);
        tail.next = makeNode(number);
    }
}
```

Your assignment of "front" only assigns the makeNode(number) value to the **local** variable.  You need to use this.front to assign the makeNode(number) to the instance variable of your node class or refactor your variable name.

```
public void addNode(node front ,int number){
    node tail;
    if(isListEmpty(front)){
        //assigns a value to the member variable "front" of your node instance
        this.front = makeNode(number); 
    } 
    else {
        tail = findTail(front);
        tail.next = makeNode(number);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do this

```
node current;
current = front;
```

but you never initial `front`, so when you call `current.next`, `current` is null.  So you can't get the next...

As an aside, why not clean up the code and do

```
node current = front;
```

Also, class names in Java should be capitalized, so `node` should be `Node`.